# PHP DST detection via date() has reversed

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, time, dst

We have run into an issue which caused havoc in our system hosted of AWS EC2.
We use PHP command of date('I') (capital i) to detect daylight saving time being in action or not. It kept returning "1" quite happily throughout the summer.

On 29/09/2018 around 7:00 am, it started returning "0", indicating a change to a winter time.
This happened pretty much exactly one full month before the change was about to happen on October 29.

As a result, we are one hour OFF on our UTC time now.
For some reason, PHP our EC2 thinks that the time has switched one month too early.

Linux Timezone is: Europe/Dublin (IST, +0100)
PHP timezone is set via date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');

```
date('I', strtotime('2018-09-29 02:00:00')) // returns "0" - which is wrong as DST is active now!
```

DST switches OFF in Ireland on 2018-10-29

```
date('I', strtotime('2018-11-29 02:00:00')) // returns "1" - which is wrong as DST is Summer time!
```

Edit: Same issue confirmed on multiple of our AWS EC2 Instances. I will contact Amazon AWS support and update this thread with a resolution.

Comment: Does `$d = new DateTime(); echo $d->format("I");` give you correct result?

Comment: No, same result - "0" for summer time. 
Note that it did return a proper result before 7 am on 29/09/2018.

Comment: super weird. I could only think that the timezone db in your PHP is broken. Your code works as expected on my PC.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly fine on the staging server (non-EC2). The issue exists only on the AWS server.

Comment: This is exactly why web apps should always work in the UTC timezone in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76983
Apparently, Dublin timezone has an exception based on some historical offset.
I am yet to fully understand the reasoning behind this, but it explains the issue technically.

Answer (score 1):

I would like share my experience regarding DST fixes on my existing products.

```
    $ssCurrentTimeZone    = date_default_timezone_get();
    $oDateTimeZone       = new DateTimeZone($ssCurrentTimeZone);
    $oDateTime           = new DateTime("now", $oDateTimeZone);
```

As above example of php is working on my existing product.
If you use `new DateTime()` then you do not need handle any DST related stuff.

Hope you can save your time with using this idea.